# VRML Loader cannot read "length"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to learn VRML Loader through following examples online. Here is my code for the loader part:

```js
var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load',function(event){
    scene.add(event.content);
});

loader.load("models/model1.WRL");
```

However, upon running the file, I receive this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The error seems to be from VRMLLoader.js line 671. Does anyone know what is wrong with my code or what other stuff that I should put in?

Comment: It seems that your model might be invalid. Does any other application load the model correctly?

Comment: @gaitat If I load this model in FreeCAD sw then its working fine.

Comment: which model are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffering from same Error. Have you tried this?

```
  var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
        var group = new THREE.Object3D();
        loader.load("../assets/models/vrml/kicad-test.wrl", function (model) {

            console.log(model);

            model.traverse(function (child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    //                    child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:0xaaaaaa});
                    console.log(child.geometry);
                }
            });
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.